# how to modify json response in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a JSON response like this

```
const json = '{"arr":[{"key1": "value1"},{"key2": "value2"}], "m":[{"key3": "value3"},{"key4": "value4"}], "b":[{"key5": "value5"},{"key6": "value6"}]}'
```

I need an array like this

```
const array = [{"key1": "value1"},{"key2": "value2"},{"key3": "value3"},{"key4": "value4"},{"key5": "value5"},{"key6": "value6"}]
```

how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tough to test with the data you supplied as it is neither valid JSON or valid JS objects. But generally speaking you want to go inside an object and spread all its keys' values. Here is the code to do that:

```js
const json = '{"arr":[{"key1": "value1"},{"key2": "value2"}], "m":[{"key3": "value3"},{"key4": "value4"}], "b":[{"key5": "value5"},{"key6": "value6"}]}'
const obj = JSON.parse(json);
const result = [];
Object.values(obj).map(item => result.push(...item))
console.log(result);
```

Again, I had to create a valid JSON string for it to work.

Also, please note that this is not a valid JS array: `[{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6}]`